# My List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces is always empty

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am implementing the MLKit face detection library with a simple application. The application is a facial monitoring system so i am setting up a preview feed from the front camera and attempting to detect a face. I am using camera2Api. At my ImageReader.onImageAvailableListener, I want to implement the firebase face detection on each read in the image. After creating my FirebaseVisionImage and running the FirebaseVisionFaceDetector I am getting an empty faces list, this should contain detected faces but I always get a face of size 0 even though a face is in the image.

I have tried other forms of creating my FirebaseVisionImage. Currently, I am creating it through the use of a byteArray which I created following the MlKit docs. I have also tried to create a FirebaseVisionImage using the media Image object.

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onPreviewImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    /**Get Image convert to Byte Array **/
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

        //Get latest image
        Image mImage = reader.acquireNextImage();

        if(mImage == null){
            return;
        }
        else {

            byte[] newImg = convertYUV420888ToNV21(mImage);

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MonitoringFeedActivity.this);

            FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions highAccuracyOpts =
                    new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                            .setPerformanceMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE)
                            .setLandmarkMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                            .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                            .build();

            int rotation = getRotationCompensation(frontCameraId,MonitoringFeedActivity.this, getApplicationContext() );

            FirebaseVisionImageMetadata metadata = new FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
                    .setWidth(480)   // 480x360 is typically sufficient for
                    .setHeight(360)  // image recognition
                    .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21)
                    .setRotation(rotation)
                    .build();

            FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteArray(newImg, metadata);

            FirebaseVisionFaceDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                    .getVisionFaceDetector(highAccuracyOpts);

            Task<List<FirebaseVisionFace>> result =
                    detector.detectInImage(image)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(
                                    new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces) {
                                            // Task completed successfully
                                            if (faces.size() != 0) {
                                                Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(faces.get(0).getSmilingProbability()));
                                            }
                                        }

                                    })
                            .addOnFailureListener(
                                    new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            // Task failed with an exception
                                            // ...
                                        }
                                    });

            mImage.close();
```

The aim is to have the resulting faces list contain the detected faces in each processed image.

Answer (score 0):

byte[] newImg = convertYUV420888ToNV21(mImage);
FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteArray(newImg, metadata);

These two lines are important. make sure Its creating proper VisionImage.

Checkout my project for all functionality

[MLKIT demo](https://github.com/Gurupreet/MLKitDemoFirebase)

Comment: For me too the same happen. I found that the issue was I dint capture a proper clear image in camera. So I tried downloading a HD image of "Taj Mahal" and then I tried to Landmark it in its processor. Then immediately the result from Google came as "Taj  Mahal" with probability rate "0.915488". So from my concern try to handle with HD image or atleast a proper image. I hope u surely get an accurate result from Google Landmark or  Face or Object Detection, etc.